# Bootstrap3 list-inline not working with form-control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with class `form- horizontal` and I am trying to get a `list-inline` working together with class `form-control`, but the two doesnt seem to work together that well:

**Without `form-control`:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label for="years_of_experience" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Time Period</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li>
                                <select >
                                    <option value="">Choose...</option>

                                </select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="text" style="width: 60px;" maxlength="4" class="year" placeholder="Year">  <span class="to">&ndash;</span>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="ended-position">
                                    <select >
                                        <option value="">Choose...</option>

                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" style="width: 60px;" maxlength="4" placeholder="Year">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renierdebruyn/Udg4X/3/)

**With `form-control`**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="years_of_experience" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Time Period</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <select class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Choose...</option>

                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 60px;" maxlength="4" class="year" placeholder="Year"> <span class="to">&ndash;</span>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="ended-position">
                                <select class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Choose...</option>

                                </select>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 60px;" maxlength="4" placeholder="Year">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renierdebruyn/Udg4X/1/)
I have googled and cannot find an answer to my question(maybe my key words are wrong).

**My question is this:**

Why is `list-inline` not working with `form-control`? and what could be a possible work-around(fix/solution)?

**UPDATE:**

I got it to be more, `inline`, but still not working correctly: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renierdebruyn/K6VJ6/6/)

Still trying to figure out Why it does not work properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not aligning inline because your are not providing the space to inline them

Solution is to assign them the `col width`,  [**working demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Udg4X/5/)

Replace simple `<li>` with `<li class="col-xs-3">` like

```
 <li class="col-xs-3">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="4" class="year" placeholder="Year" />
 </li>
```

**Why this works??** : since you didnt mention the `col` size, all the `<li>` align as per their `width` thereby misplacing other `<li>` next to them

Comment: thanks for your answers... both worked @Surjith, but this answer was more applicable as I am using horizontal forms...

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, and for Bootstrap 4 users.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item">Menu 1</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Menu 2</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Menu3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because form-control uses `display:block` and `width:100%` property. To make it work override the classes.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/Udg4X/6/)**

**CSS**

```
.form-control {
    display:inline;
    width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Fiddle :-

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6VJ6/)

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="bs-example">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge">14</span>
Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge">2</span>
Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> <span class="badge">1</span>
Morbi leo risus</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to change your CSS file. I just changed the Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: thanks for your response... This is an idea I can play with for the time being.Your answer is not perfect but I play with it.But I would still like to know why `list-inline` does not work with `form-control`.